# When synth or deploy with AWS CDK getting bundling error related to knex

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, knex.js, esbuild, aws-cdk-typescript

I am using only the `mssql` client. But I am getting below bundling errors when I try to run `cdk synth`.

- Node.js - v18.16.0
- CDK - 2.95.1
- knex - 2.5.1

```
dirname /.../my-repo/cdk/my-app/lib/lambda
Bundling asset api---app/get-last-sales-no/Code/Stage...
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "sqlite3"

    node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/sqlite3/index.js:42:19:
      42 │     return require('sqlite3');
         ╵                    ~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "sqlite3" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this
  error. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at
  run-time instead of bundle-time.

✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "pg"

    node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/pgnative/index.js:13:19:
      13 │     return require('pg').native;
         ╵                    ~~~~

  You can mark the path "pg" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this
  error. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at
  run-time instead of bundle-time.

✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "mysql2"

    node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/mysql2/index.js:15:19:
      15 │     return require('mysql2');
         ╵                    ~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "mysql2" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this
  error. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at
  run-time instead of bundle-time.

✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "pg"

    node_modules/knex/lib/dialects/redshift/index.js:44:19:
      44 │     return require('pg');
         ╵                    ~~~~

  You can mark the path "pg" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this
  error. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at
  run-time instead of bundle-time.
```

Did some research and found out that some got this fixed by marking `knex` itself or the client dependencies as external for `esbuild`. The thing is I am not using `esbuild` directly. AWS CDK should be using it under the hood I guess.

Anyway to fix this?

Comment: What's the CDK construct you're using?

Comment: @gshpychka I am new to CDK. I think I am not using any construct. This is caused by `aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs`

Comment: You are using the `NodejsFunction` construct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by defining [external modules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs-readme.html#externals) for esbuild bundler used under the hood by `aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs`

```
const lambdaFunction = new NodejsFunction(instance, 'get-last-sales-no', {
    bundling: {
      externalModules: [
        'sqlite3',
        'mysql',
        'oracledb',
        'mysql2',
        'pg',
        'pg-query-stream',
      ],
    },
    ...
});
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda_nodejs-readme.html#externals

Answer (score 0):

For those who uses SAM at yml file:

**External: !Split [" ", !Ref ExternalDependencies]** inside Metadata's BuildProperties while having it on parameter so that if you need it in multiple functions just one line will do that

```yaml
Parameters:
  ExternalDependencies:
    Type: String
    Default: "mysql2 better-sqlite3 oracledb mysql tedious pg-query-stream sqlite3"

Resources:
  someFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: ....
      Handler: ....
      Role: ....
    Metadata:
      BuildMethod: esbuild
      BuildProperties:
        ....
        External: !Split [" ", !Ref ExternalDependencies]
        ....
```